# Cordova 6.0.0 not supporting api level below 23

Tags: cordova

I am getting  error when building the  ionic projects using cordova 6.0.0.
Manifest not accepting minimum API level below 23.

please give me appropriate solution.

Comment: Solution: set your minimum API level to 23, or select another cordova version

Comment: if i select API level 23 then my app will not work on old devices having API below 23

Comment: As I see, minimum API level for cordova 6.0.0 is 14. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html can you post your error?